# Can Laminate flooring be installed on Steps?

Tags: flooring, stairs

Can Laminate flooring be installed on steps?  I've seen that many laminate flooring manufacturers offer stair nose pieces like this.  It would seem that you would fasten (with finish nails) the thick part of this nose to the step, and that this would provide the "4th wall" that you need for floating laminate floor installation.

The flooring person at the local "Big Box" store said this couldn't be done, however.

[image]

Just curious if this can be done or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  That's for the top of the staircase where the floor runs out.
Stairs need to be extremely stable.  Any movement at all can lead to disaster.

Your best bets are to refinish (tough) or carpet.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  The person at the big box store couldn't tell me why, but you just did.